# Having trouble loading tidyverse library

Tags: r, tidyverse, install.packages, stringi

> ```
> install.packages("dslabs")
> install.packages("tidyverse")
> library(dslabs)
> library(tidyverse)
> data(murders)> murders %>%
> +   ggplot(aes (population, total, label=abb, color=region)) +
> +   geom_label()
> Error in murders %>% ggplot(aes(population, total, label = abb, color = region)) : 
>   could not find function "%>%"
> > murders |>
> +   ggplot(aes (population, total, label=abb, color=region)) +
> +   geom_label()
> Error in ggplot(murders, aes(population, total, label = abb, color = region)) : 
>   could not find function "ggplot"
> ```

Numerous errors with R-4.2.2 in R Studio 2022.12.15 with RTools 4.2.  I just tried to reinstall and I got the following error:

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>  there is no package called ‘stringi’
> ```

Tried two different computers.  Tried all the suggestions I could possibly find online (installing and loading `magrittr`, `dplyr`, or replacing pipe operator).  Finally replacing the pipe operator worked, I think, but then other terms aren't recognized, as if `tidyverse` is not installed.

It has to be something basic I'm doing wrong, repeatedly.  I restarted everything after installing `stringi`, and when I loaded `tidyverse` now I get this message, which could explain why the pipe operator is not being recognized:

> ```
> > library(tidyverse)
> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
>     ✔ ggplot2 3.4.0      ✔ purrr   1.0.1 
>     ✔ tibble  3.1.8      ✔ dplyr   1.0.10
>     ✔ tidyr   1.2.1      ✔ stringr 1.5.0 
>     ✔ readr   2.1.3      ✔ forcats 0.5.2 
>     ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────── 
>     tidyverse_conflicts() ──
>     ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
>     ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> ```

Comment: Could you please try installing the `stringi` package?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion in the comments, I installed the `stringi` package, which totally worked once I restarted my computer and reran my script.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stake Overflow, please note its preferable to leave "Thanks" style notes as comments instead of answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: The answer was left as a comment, so I left a thank you as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows after every line of code to run script line-by-line. Remember to save the file first, because there is no mistake in the code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34858923)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).